# Fix images for which the mime type can not be detected

Tags: bash, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I have a *lot* of images that I need to process using a third party PHP tool. All these images are GIFs, JPEGs or PNGs. However, on some of the images I get an error because of an incorrect mime type. Turns out that some images (mostly JPG files) are detected as "application/octet-stream".

Whenever I open the image an any viewer, all seems ok. After resaving such an image using Photoshop, the mime type is detected correctly as "image/jpeg". I'm just not exited about opening and resaving thousands of images.

I've constructed a list of filenames for which the problem occurs. Is there any way to 'fix' the image such that the correct mime type is detected?

I've found the incorrect mime types using the following command:
`file --mime-type <filename>`

**Here are some example images:**

- [Example of problem 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_lc6RkVy-1ZEIzZ0hTZDZBdEE/view?usp=sharing)
- [Example of problem 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_lc6RkVy-1VWptZFdlNVllRms/view?usp=sharing)
- [Example of an image that has no problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_lc6RkVy-1d0FWWkhmenE4SVk/view?usp=sharing)

Running `identify -ping -verbose <filename>` doesn't return a mime type only a *Format*. The format is `Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)` for all JPG images with or without correct mime.

**Some more info about versions:**

```
$ file --version
file-5.14
magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic

$ identify --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Comment: Huh? AFAIK images don't have a MIME type embedded in them - it is normally added by the web server so where are your MIME types actually stored or actually coming from?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've updated the text to reflect that mime types are actually detected and not embedded in the files.

Comment: If you're going to answer your own question, please do it as an answer. Also - you question is still very poorly worded. I still have no idea what your actual problem is.

Comment: @Danack I've put the shell script in an answer. Unfortunately, I cannot rephrase the question any better than I already did or tell you what the problem is. Since I don't know what the actual problem is, I only see that I get a wrong mime type for some images when using the ```file``` command. Exactly the same images can not be imported in my PHP/imagick based app. Running ```convert``` fixes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically you are saying that

```
file --mime-type <filename>
```

doesn't work? If so, try asking ImageMagick to work it out for you:

```
identify -ping -verbose someImage.jpg | awk '/Mime type:/{print $NF}'
```

Or post a couple of troublesome images so that other folks can test it out.

Maybe you can use ImageMagick to rewrite the file and then `file --mime-type` will work. Try running this:

```
convert troubleFile.jpg rebuilt.jpg
```

and see if `file --mime-type rebuilt.jpg` works.

Comment: I've edited the original post with some more information and some sample images.

Comment: Glad it works for you! Before you use `convert` to re-encode thousands of files, please try and make a backup and keep it around for a while. Also, check that any image meta-data you need is preserved (copyright, GPS location, tags etc). Also, check the newly encoded files are not too much bigger than the originals. Also, note that `convert` can work in-place without problem - you can use the same output file as input file.

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone who runs into the same issue. Based on Mark Setchell's answer I created the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]] || [[ $# -gt 2 ]];
then
  echo "Usage $0 <directory> [<backupdir>]"
  exit
fi

for FILENAME in $(find $1 -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\|jpeg\)");
do
  MIME=$(file --mime-type "$FILENAME" | awk '{print $NF}')
  if [ "$MIME" == "application/octet-stream" ]
  then
    echo "$FILENAME has mime type $MIME:"
    if [[ ! -z $2 ]];
    then
      echo "  - Creating backup"
      cp "$FILENAME" "$2"
    fi
    echo "  - Running convert"
    convert "$FILENAME" "$FILENAME"
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];
    then
      echo "  - Done!"
    else
      echo "  - Error!"
      echo "$FILENAME" >> errors.txt
    fi
  fi
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

It will search a directory recursively for jpg/png/gif files and checks the mime type. If the mime type is `"application/octet-stream"` it will try to convert the image without actually performing any visible change in the image. After this operation the correct mime type will be detected.

Images that could not be converted will get logged in `errors.txt`. You can also provide a backup directory in which the original files will be saved.

Comment: Nice! Kudos for sharing!